# Javascript toggle issue

Tags: javascript

We have a bit of old code that's in our website, and I can't seem to find why it's not working properly, so I'm wondering if fresh eyes can see what I can't.
These are the functions:

```
    function Toggle(item) {
   obj=document.getElementById(item);
   visible=(obj.style.display!="none")
   key=document.getElementById("x" + item);
   if (visible) {
     key.innerHTML="<img src='/images/common/leftsidebullet_closed.gif' height=10 width=10 border=0>";
     obj.style.display="none";
   } else {
      key.innerHTML="<img src='/images/common/leftsidebullet_opened.gif' height=10 width=10 border=0>";
      obj.style.display="block";
   }
}

function Toggle2(item) {
   obj=document.getElementById(item);
   visible=(obj.style.display!="none")
   key=document.getElementById("x" + item);
   if (visible) {
     obj.style.display="none";
     key.innerHTML="<img src='/images/common/leftsidebullet_closedOrange.gif' height=10 width=10 border=0>";
   } else {
      obj.style.display="block";
      key.innerHTML="<img src='/images/common/leftsidebullet_openedOrange.gif' height=10 width=10 border=0>";
   }
}
```

And the example page is located [here](http://ads-pipe.com/en/documentlisting.asp?documenttypeID=682)
If you click on the "Section 1 – Specifications" list item in the middle of the page, it requires two clicks to actually fire the toggle instead of it doing it the first time.
It's not creating an error and I can't think of anything else so I thought I'd ask if someone else can see something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at page load the `display` property is set to `''` (in Chrome). Which is different from `'none'`. So `visible` is falsely set at `true`. So your script wants to hide the div by setting the `display` property at `'none'`. The second time you click, the script evaluates `visible` to `false`. So it shows the div by setting the property to `block`.

Quick fix:

```
visible=(obj.style.display=="block")
```

in stead of

```
visible=(obj.style.display!="none")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick. I was pretty sure that it had something to do with "visible" not being set properly, but I didn't notice the "none" instead of "block".

Answer (score 0):

As Jan says... so try this:

```
 visible=!(obj.style.display==="block");
```

Will plug into your existing code -- or you can take out the `!` and switch your if statements around.